# how can I find the artifactId and version information for '"libopencv_java.so" and "libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so" in pom.xml in Maven?

Tags: maven, opencv, dependencies

I've searched for hours but no artifactId and version information for "libopencv_java.so" and "libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so".. I know how to add dependency into pom.xml to be included in lib/armeabi in .apk, but I just cannot find the correct information.. The pox.xml keeps complaining

"Missing artifact org.opencv:libnative_camera_r2.2.2:so:2.2.2
Missing artifact org.opencv:libopencv_java:so:1.0"

Thank you so much~!!

Comment: Your dependencies are native libraries (.so). As far as I know, this kind of files are not managed by Maven.

Answer (score 0):

These are native non-Java libraries. They aren't normally handled by Maven. If you would like to use static objects in your module, I suggest you have something like `${basedir}/lib` and place your static libraries in there. Add the directory as a `<resource/>` as well and have it included in you jar. I think it should be possible to load the .so from within the jar. This is one option.

Another option would be, (if you really, really must re-use the .so-s across modules), to extract them to a separate module and have your module depend on that one.

Either way, you'll need to do quite a bit of magic, which isn't covered by Maven by default.

Comment: thanks. I already added the static library in system path, which worked well. And for native library, there is no .so generated. I've tried a lot of methods, nothing worked.